# How do I run this code with functions for strings

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to obtain a result for this:

```
function getAttackString() {
var foo = "d3294hb34";
var bar = "x338p5ij8";
return "The code is: "+(foo.substr(3,foo.length-6))+(bar.substr(2));
}
```

And have tried to do so by running the following script on HTML

```
<p id="demo"></p>   

function getAttackString(a, b) {
    return (a.substr(3,a.length-6))+(b.substr(2));
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getAttackString(d3294hb34, x338p5ij8);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the problem? I find this question to be pretty unclear.

Comment: Did you intend to wrap `d3294hb34` and the other in quotes? If you're getting an error, you need to post it. "It doesn't work" is exceedingly unhelpful.

Comment: Check your console for errors ...likely see that `d3294hb34 is undefined` ...because it's not a string

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getAttackString(d3294hb34, x338p5ij8);
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getAttackString("d3294hb34", "x338p5ij8");
```